# Redirect after action, how is it possible?

Tags: php, html

it is creating the new file, but not redirecting to the new page. why and whats the solution or alternatives. thanks

```
    <?php 

        $newfile = $_GET['abc'];
        $file = 'example.com.php';
        $url = 'example.com/"$newfile"';

        {if (!copy($file, $newfile)) 
        {


   echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo '<form onsubmit='.$url.'>;</form>;';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<noscript>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
            echo '</noscript>';}
    else{};   };

    ?>

    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="abc" placeholder="Type Here. . .">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>``
```

if someone like to know what I am doing:
on user input, create a page with input, and get redirected to that newly formed page. (these pages will be temporary, and will be deleted on exit)

Comment: Whats the extra curly brace outside the `if`? Your `$url` wont have the `GET` value in it you need to use the double quotes for the whole value. E.G. `"example.com/$newfile";` or `'example.com/' . $newfile;`"

Comment: What is it doing with the current code?

Comment: @chris85 I actually know that, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should never take raw user input and work directly in the file system.**

This code should give you what you need.
You were mixing onsubmit and meta refresh and browser side code with server side.

```
<?php 

if( array_key_exists( 'abc', $_GET ) )
{
    $newfile = $_GET['abc'];
    $file = 'example.com.php';
    $url = "http://localhost/so/29835025/$newfile";

    if ( copy( $file, $newfile ) )
    {
        header( "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" );
        header( 'Location: ' . $url );
        exit();
    }
}

?>

<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="abc" placeholder="Type Here. . .">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

**Note:** *Best practice is to send full URL in your HTTP location header.  I put this code on my localhost for testing - you'll need to change your url accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

What about using this javascript instead of meta refresh? Meta refresh will only work if headers haven't been declared, perhaps this is your problem?

```
<script>
    var newURL =  <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>"; 
    window.location = newURL;
</script>
```

Comment: Did you remove the extra curly braces as suggested by @chris85 ?